# Java String.split with multiple character delimeter

Tags: java, regex, string

I have strings that I need to parse that look like this

```
"(1,0,quote),(1,0,place),(1,0,hall),(2,0,wall)"
```

I want to split the string into chunks of triplets so that I get

```
1,0,quote 
1,0,place 
1,0,hall 
2,0,wall
```

How can I do this with String.split? If I use a comma as a delimeter, it would split the words too. I want to split them using the delimeter "),(". How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use a regex or write a real parser, if you need to handle arbitrarily-nested `()`s. Or use a real serialization that already solves this problem: JSON.

Comment: Why not remove the first and last character, then split them by `),(` like you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `split` method, you'll get an array with one empty cell. Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` class instead.

Try this code instead:

```
String s = "(1,0,quote),(1,0,place),(1,0,hall),(2,0,wall)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+,\\d+,[^)]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

List<String> l=new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    l.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(l);
```

**Output**

```
[1,0,quote, 1,0,place, 1,0,hall, 2,0,wall]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you split your string with `),(` you will not remove `(` from start and `)` at end of your string. Consider using Pattern and Matcher classes to find elements between `(` `)`.

```
String text = "(1,0,quote),(1,0,place),(1,0,hall),(2,0,wall)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
1,0,quote
1,0,place
1,0,hall
2,0,wall
```

---

If you really want to use `split` on `),(` you will need to manually remove first `(` and last `)` (splitting will only remove part that should be split on). Also you will have to escape parenthesis `)` `(` because they are regex metacharacter (for example used to create groups). To do this you can manually add `\\` before each of `)` and `(`, or you can surround `),(` with `\\Q` and `\\E` to mark characters between these elements as literals. BUT you don't have to do this manually. Just use `Pattern.quote` to produce regex with escaped all metacharacters and use it as `split` argument like

```
//I assume that `text` already removed `(` and `)` from its start and end 
String[] array = text.split(Pattern.quote("),("));
```

Comment: Yeah. I actually made a more specific regex expression \(([^,]+[,]){2}[^,]+\) . It also rules out instances in which the name has brackets.

Comment: @Franzd'Anconia A little optimization for the  regexp, `[,]` can be replaced simply by `,`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you can split at `),(` - then, when iterating over the result array, you only need to take into account, that `array[0]` contains an additional `(` and `array[n-1]` contains an additional `)`.

You could also apply a regex to remove the leading and trailing bracket, first or use substring from `1` to `n-2` before splitting, etc...